# Is it ok to use std::variant of std::variants

Tags: c++, variant

I'm trying to combine two variants into one variant just for readability. This is the code:

```
using VariantType_basic = std::variant<int8_t, uint8_t, int16_t, uint16_t, int32_t, uint32_t, int64_t, uint64_t, std::string>;
using VariantType_vector = std::variant<vector<int8_t>, vector<uint8_t>, vector<int16_t>, vector<uint16_t>, vector<int32_t>, vector<uint32_t>, vector<int64_t>, vector<uint64_t>, vector<std::string>>;
using VariantType_all = std::variant<VariantType_basic, VariantType_vector>;

class Container {
    public:
        Container(){}
        template<typename T>
        T get(string key, bool &found){
            found = false;
            T result;
            auto elem = m_internal_map.find(key);
            if(elem != m_internal_map.end())
                std::visit( 
                    [&](const auto& v){ 
                        // if(holds_alternative<T>(v)){

                        result = std::get<T>(v);
                        found = true;
                    //} 
                },  
                    elem->second 
                    );

            return result;
        }

        template<typename T>
        void put(string key, T&elem){

        }
    private:
        map<string, VariantType_all> m_internal_map;
};
```

The get() method fails at compile time at `result = std::get<T>(v);` when I try to do something like this:

```
Container cont;
bool found;
cont.get<uint16_t>("www", found);
```

The error message is huge but the first error message is this: `/usr/include/c++/7/variant:762:7: error: static assertion failed: T should occur for exactly once in alternatives`

Should I stop trying to use variant of variants ?

Comment: `result = std::get<T>(v);` will be either `VariantType_basic` or `VariantType_vector`, but not `uint16_t`, I guess.

Comment: Isn't v variable of type VariantType_vector  or VariantType_basic ? so if you do get on v I would expect the result to be of type uint16_t

Comment: Two level variant is awkward to use, in my opinion.  `VariantType_all v = VariantType_basic{string("Hello")}; string s = std::get<string>(std::get<VariantType_basic>(v));`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest to "flatten" the variants instead of having variant of variants:

```
template <typename Var1, typename Var2> struct variant_flat;

template <typename ... Ts1, typename ... Ts2>
struct variant_flat<std::variant<Ts1...>, std::variant<Ts2...>>
{
    using type = std::variant<Ts1..., Ts2...>;
};

using VariantType_basic = std::variant<int8_t, uint8_t, int16_t, uint16_t, int32_t, uint32_t, int64_t, uint64_t, std::string>;
using VariantType_vector = std::variant<std::vector<int8_t>, std::vector<uint8_t>, std::vector<int16_t>, std::vector<uint16_t>, std::vector<int32_t>, std::vector<uint32_t>, std::vector<int64_t>, std::vector<uint64_t>, std::vector<std::string>>;
using VariantType_all = variant_flat<VariantType_basic, VariantType_vector>::type;
```

And than your class has just to handle one variant level:

```
class Container
{
public:
    Container(){}

    template<typename T>
    T get(const std::string& key, bool &found) const {
        found = false;
        T result;
        auto elem = m_internal_map.find(key);
        if (elem != m_internal_map.end() && std::holds_alternative<T>(elem->second)){
            result = std::get<T>(elem->second);
            found = true;
        }
        return result;
    }

    template<typename T>
    void put(const std::string& key, const T& elem) {
        m_internal_map[key] = elem;
    }
private:
    std::map<std::string, VariantType_all> m_internal_map;
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1aca90574808330f)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `std::visit` will instantiate calls to your lambda for *all* variant types at compiletime and then just picks the one corresponding to the actual value contained within your variant at runtime. With the way the lambda is currently written, this means that it'll try to instantiate

```cpp
result = std::get<T>(v);
```

for your given `T` with both, a version of the lambda for the case of `VariantType_basic` as well as for the case of `VariantType_vector`. Since your `VariantType_vector` does not at all contain a `std::uint16_t`, this second instantiation will fail to compile with the given error since you're attempting to call `std::get<T>` on a type that does not contain `T` in the list of alternatives at all…

One way to solve this problem would be to write your visitor lambda such that the code that calls `std::get<T>` is only instantiated for variant values that are variants that actually may contain a value of the type you're looking for:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename V>
constexpr bool has_variant = false;

template <typename T, typename... Types>
constexpr bool has_variant<T, std::variant<Types...>> = (std::is_same_v<T, Types> || ...);

template <typename T, typename V>
constexpr bool has_variant<T, V&> = has_variant<T, V>;
```

and then

```cpp
            std::visit([&](const auto& v)
            {
                if constexpr (has_variant<decltype(v), T>)
                {
                    result = std::get<T>(v);
                    found = true;
                }
                else
                    found = false;
            }, elem->second);
```

All that being said, this whole construction appears to me a pretty brittle solution for a problem that can probably be solved better in a different way. I would recommend to reconsider your approach here…

Answer (score 0):

You can use a second level of `visit` to descend into your nested variant:

```
template < typename T >
struct Getter
{
    T& value;
    bool& found;
    void operator()(const T& t)
    {
        value = t;
        found = true;
    }
    template < typename U >
    void operator()(const U& u) {}
};

if(elem != m_internal_map.end()) {
   Getter< T > getter = { result, found };
   std::visit( getter, elem->second );
}
```

If the type isn't the desired type then `Getter` will ignore it. Note that `Getter` will also capture values convertible to `T` so might not be what you want.

Using a single level of variant would definitely be simpler.